# Angular 2 show popup and redirect

Tags: angular

I need show popup showing some message and then redirect to another component.But the thing is it doesn't show popup but redirecting to another component.i have tried the following code which redirects to another component.Since i'm newbie to angular 2 kindly help me.

Note : popwindow is showing if i dnt redirect to another component

```
import { Component,OnInit, ViewEncapsulation,ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpService } from 'app/http.service';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { Overlay } from 'angular2-modal';
    import { Modal } from 'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-registration',
      templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./registration.component.css'],
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    })
    export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {


      constructor(private httpService : HttpService,private router: Router,overlay: Overlay, vcRef: ViewContainerRef, public modal: Modal) {
        overlay.defaultViewContainer = vcRef;
       }

      ngOnInit() {
      }



      onsubmit(form: NgForm){
        this.httpService.sendData(form.value).subscribe(data =>{
          if(data.data == 1 ){this.modal.alert().title('Message').body('Successfully registered').open();
           this.router.navigate(['/login']);}

      },error => {
        if(error)
        {
          this.modal.alert().title('Message').body('Server is not reachable').open();
        }
      });

      }

    }
```

Comment: it's because right after calling the modal.alert(), login component gets loaded. SO, to get things going, you can call the modal popup after getting redirected to login component. Call the modal.alert() from login component or add a delay in the current code.. so that redirection happens after some seconds

Comment: can you tell how can i add delay to my router

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
onsubmit(form: NgForm){
        this.httpService.sendData(form.value).subscribe(data =>{
        if(data.data == 1 ){this.modal.alert().title('Message').body('Successfully registered').open();
        setTimeout(() => {
           this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because you don't wait between your instructions.

You can add before `this.router.navigate(['/login']);` a timer instruction may be 2 seconds.

Comment: can you elaborate your answer how can set the timer before redirect

Comment: setTimeout(() => {
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}, 3000);