# Calling controller, but not redirecting to another view immediately

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I am working with ASP.NET Core.

I wanted to add simple login functionality to my application.

So I have form to fill password and login and button to submit data.

When submitting data, I create HTTP POST request, which calls appropriate method in my controller. The result of a controller is another view, to which user is redirected (based on login result).

What I want to do is: call controller just to check if login was successfull, based on that result, **without redirecting to other page**, I want to show some pop-up about success of a login, and then redirect to appropriate view.

What I can think of is to call controller two times: first for login vaildation and second for redirecting. Is this right way? Or is there any better approach?

Another way I thought of is to create HTTP request with JavaScript after showing pop-up.

Comment: Sending two requests does makes sense to me. First request You're checking authentication -You don't want to redirect. If you're authenticated and your display of authentication condition is met, then you want to perform a redirect.  I'm unsure what your frontend is or you exact display conditions. but with something like angular you could do something like this either, to save the expense of two requests. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137987/angular-2-show-popup-and-redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your scenario, the best way would be to use `AJAX` to send your form data to the `Controller` method and based on the response from your `Controller` method, perform the appropriate action on your `View`. A very simple example would be:

Example View:

```
  <table class="table table-striped">    
    <tr>
      <td>Username: </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password: </td>
      <td><input type="password" class="form-control" id="userpassword" required></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="box-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AuthenticateUser()">Submit</button>
  </div>

<script>
function AuthenticateUser() {
  var username= $("#username").val();
  var password= $("#userpassword").val();

  var json = {
          username: username,
          password: password,
         };

  $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {"json": JSON.stringify(json)},,
      url: "@Url.Action("AuthenticateUser","Home")",
      success: function (data) {
          if(data.status=="true")
          {
            var urlToRedirect= '@Url.Action("RedirectMethod","Home")';
            window.location.href = urlToRedirect; //Redirect here
          }
          else if(data.status=="false")
          {
            alert(data.msg)
          }
      },
      error:function(err){
          console.log(err);
      }            
  });
}
</script>
```

Example `Controller` method:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AuthenticateUser(string json)
{

  var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));

  //Get your variables here from AJAX call
  var username= jsondata["username"];
  var password= jsondata["password"];

  bool result=db.Authenticate(username,password) //Can be API call or DB call 

  if(bool)
  {
   return Json(new {status="true", msg= "successful authentication"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  else
  {
   return Json(new {status="false", msg= "Incorrect credentials given"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }

}
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: After few minor changes, it is solution I was thinking about and I think it's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can try returning a boolean value by your controller method based on successful/unsuccessful login by the user. Then you can use this result for showing the pop-up, And then redirect user from that pop-up.
Creating HTTP request from JavaScript is also a good option.